# str_replace URL space

Tags: php

I'm making a website where im alowing my users (after that they are loged in) to Add a (car) advertisement!

I have a form where the user can submit his car information.(add-vehicle.php)
Now I want to display each new advertisement in my list-view. (car-list.php)
How can I do this?

Comment: there is no db related code in this question

Comment: urlencode() might work better

Answer (score 1):

I recommand to use `urlencode('string')`

and then later when get your variable with `urldecode('string')`

Response to your comment:

```
if (isset($_GET['merk'],$_GET['car_id'],$_GET['titel']) === true ) 
{ 
$merk = urldecode(trim ($_GET['merk'])); 
$car_id = urldecode(trim($_GET['car_id'])); 
$titel = urldecode(trim($_GET['titel'])); 
}
```

Comment: if   (isset($_GET['merk'],$_GET['car_id'],$_GET['titel']) === true ) {
  $merk = trim ($_GET['merk']);
  $car_id = trim($_GET['car_id']);
  $titel = trim($_GET['titel']);
Where/how should I use urlencode?

And i have replaced .str_replace ==> .urldecode($merk).
Is this Good. (Sorry i'm a beginner at this topic)

Comment: Thx for youre comment.
The value of $merk in my database= Aston Martin,and
$titel=Aston Martin, In good condition!!

This is what I get in my URL now: 
merk=Aston+Martin&titel=Aston+Martin%2C+In+good+condition%21%21

Answer (score 1):

Use urlencode /urldecode to pass variables in url's [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're changing a space into a hyphen.  If it is stored in the database as a space, it will never find it because "This Entry" is different from "This-Entry".  As others said, urlencode will work better, but if you still want to replace the space with a hyphen, just make sure that it is done the same in the database as well.

Answer (score 0):

First, nobody in this world will know what you have in your database to tell what's the problem! At least post an example data.

Second, you must be sure of what you have and what you are comparing to.

You are basically asking if **a** is equal to **b** and to be fair that's something that you should be able to tell if you're programming!

Third, you should implement a methodology that allows you to quickly test your code, and that's from printing your data to the browser to a fully automated test.